# How to organize a communication site department-wise?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, site-collection, administration, communication-site

I'm planning to create 1 HR communication site with 4 document libraries (IT, Legal, Marketing, Sales), and 4 pages (IT, Legal, Marketing, Sales). Each page will contain the respective document library and some articles applicable for that department. The site will have navigation bar taking the user to each page. Only members of the respective department (we have Azure AD groups per department) should be able to access that department's page/documents.

For example: I want to allow only members of IT to view the IT page. Does SharePoint allow me to apply permission at page level? If so, then do I also need to apply the permission at document library level?

Is there a better solution, for example instead of pages do I create 1 site for each department? or maybe 1 sub-site for each department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best possible solution will be to create a separate site (site collection) for each department.

In the modern SharePoint experience, sub-sites are not recommended and Microsoft recommends using "flat" structure for creating sites instead of sub-sites. So, in the new "flat" world of modern SharePoint, plan to create one site for each department in organization.

Also, if you want to connect multiple sites to search the content across all sites, Microsoft recommends using "Hub" sites for this.

Check below Microsoft official documentation for more understanding: [Introduction to SharePoint information architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/information-architecture-modern-experience)

Comment: So rather than site having navigation to multiple subsites, you are saying the recommendation is to use 1 hub site, and 1 site per department?

Comment: You can create 1 site per department and add navigation for any site in navigation of any site other site. But, if you want to search content across all connected sites or apply common navigation, branding, and site structure across associated sites, you can use hub site (For your case, I don't think you want to search content across all sites and it should be visible to everyone, right? In that case, you can ignore hub site explanation in answer).

Comment: If I don't use hub site, then within each site can I search for documents from document library in that site?

Comment: Yes, you can search the documents within same site.